# How to display OpenStreetMap Tags in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to display certain tags of OpenStreetMap in my Qt app. For example, I want to be able to display all `drink:coffee` tags in the map.
Displaying a map with QtLocation is no problem.

Here you can see a map example:
https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qtlocation-minimal-map-example.html

This is how I want to display the data in Qt: https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/drink%3Acoffee#map

Thank you!

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtlocation-places-map-example.html) example, [PlaceSearchModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-placesearchmodel.html)?

Comment: Yes I have, thanks. But it's not working with the search engine.